# Kotlin reflection is not available

Tags: kotlin, higher-order-functions

I was trying to learn higher order functions from the first example of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7QpoMj2uIA). Here's my code and output.

**Code**

```
fun lowercase(value: String) = value.toLowerCase()

fun higherOrder(value:String, op: (String) -> String) : String {
    println("Executing higher order fun $op")
    return op(value)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(higherOrder("HELLO", ::lowercase))
    println(higherOrder("hello", {it -> lowercase(it)}))
    println(higherOrder("HeLlo", { x -> lowercase(x) }))
    println(higherOrder("Hello", { lowercase(it) }))
}
```

**Output**

```
Executing higher order fun function lowercase (Kotlin reflection is not available)
hello
Executing higher order fun Function1<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>
hello
Executing higher order fun Function1<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>
hello
Executing higher order fun Function1<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>
hello

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So my question is, why does it print **Kotlin reflection is not available**?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Full reflection requires the `kotlin-reflect` library in addition to `kotlin-stdlib`.
If full reflection is available it will probably have a more comprehensive `toString()`, hence the message.

Comment: Yup. That's it. Adding `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"` to build.gradle fixed the issue.

Comment: Adding the reflect library fixed the issue (great!) on my builds but does not let me Build an APK. The compiler throws an `Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.` Any ideas why, or how to fix it?

Comment: @LucasP.  `kotlin-reflect` contains a lot of methods and likely pushed your APK method counts above the 64K limit. You can fix it by enabling [multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex), using [kotlin.reflect.lite](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.reflect.lite) instead (if applicable), or simply ignoring the warning

Comment: This appears to have been fixed in version 1.3

Comment: Add this library [kotlin-reflect](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.4.31)

Answer (score 0):

add `kotlin-reflect` library

```
 implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0'
```

I try it, it works.